# Algorithmic combinatorial discrete problem (randomized lazy update?)

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

We are given a vector $\mathbf{b}$ of size $h$. Initially we have $\mathbf{b}_i=1$ for all $i\in \{1, 2, \ldots, h\}$. In a sequential fashion, at each time step $t=1, \ldots, n$, an index $j(t)$ is (adversarially) selected from $\{1, 2, \ldots, h\}$, $\mathbf{b}_{j(t)}$ is incremented by $1$, and the only information we receive is index $j(t)$.

We are also given a vector of integers $\mathbf{a}$ of size $h$. Our goal is to maintain ***over time*** vector $\mathbf{a}$, such that, ***at each time step*** ***for all $i\in \{1, 2, \ldots, h\}$*** we have that $\mathbf{a}_i$ is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^i \mathbf{b}_k$ ***up to a constant factor*** (even a *logarithmic factor in $n$ or $h$* would be acceptable). Initially (at time step $0$) each integer $\mathbf{a}_i$ is set to be equal to $\sum_{k=1}^i \mathbf{b}_k$ which in turn is equal to $i$.

---

**Question:** How can we build an algorithmic (*possibly randomized*) strategy to maintain ***over time*** vector $\mathbf{a}$ with a ***total*** (*expected* if randomized) number of elementary operations (i.e., the algorithmic time complexity) equal to $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ (or, if possible, $\mathcal{O}(n)$)?

Comment: If I understood correctly, one structure that helps you to do so is a Persistent Segment Tree.

Comment: Thank you Luis. With Persistent Segment Trees one can answer queries related to the sum of intervals in an array, which in this case corresponds to the the array $B[i]$ for $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,h\}$ of bins. Here, instead, we want to maintain $A[\cdot]$ updated overtime (up to a constant factor as I wrote above the question). This seems much more difficult, because, for any given approximation threshold, adding just one ball can require to simultaneously update $\Theta(h)$-many records of $A[\cdot]$. If you have any idea, I would be very happy to know it!

Comment: I think there is a trick for range updates on Segment Trees called "lazy propagation" which is useful.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at that.

Comment: I just changed array $A[\cdot]$ and $B[\cdot]$ into vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ only for notational purpose.

Comment: Do you want all of $\boldsymbol a$ to exist all the time, or do you just want to find $a_i$ when you need it?

Comment: The whole vector $\mathbf{a}$ with all its $h$ components, all the time.